# Reduced residue classes the same as multiplicative group of integers?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I cannot find a definition for the group of reduced residue classes.
Are  the multiplicative group of integers modulo n the same thing?

The integers coprime to n from the set ${\displaystyle \{0,1,\dots ,n-1\}}$ of $n$ non-negative integers form a group under multiplication modulo $n$, called the multiplicative group of integers modulo n.
Is this the same as the reduced residue classes $n$.

Comment: This group is often denoted by $U(n)$, where $U$ stands for units. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276644/prove-that-that-un-is-an-abelian-group). Indeed we have $U(n)=(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^{\times}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reduced residue class modulo $n$ are the remainders of $\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$ that are relatively prime to $n$. This is equivalent to having a multiplicative inverse modulo $n$. The remainders $1$ and $n-1$ are always two of them.