# Let $U_n = \{[a] \in \Bbb Z_n \mid \gcd(a,n)=1 \}$. Show that $(U_n,\cdot_n)$ is a group under multiplication modulo $n$.

Tags: group-theory

**edit:**

Let $U_n = \{[a] \in \Bbb Z_n \mid \gcd(a,n)=1 \}$. Show that $(U_n,\cdot_n)$ is a group, where $\cdot_n$ is the multiplication modulo $n$.

**Attempt:**
For the convenience and to simplify, write
$[a] \cdot_n [b] = [a][b]$.
First, we show that $\cdot_n$ is a binary operation:

**Claim.** The multiplicative inverse modulo $n$ of $[a]$ is exist for all $[a] \in U_n$.

**Proof.** Let $[a] \in U_n$.
Then, $\gcd(a,n) = 1$. By Bezout's Lemma, there are exist $x,y \in \Bbb Z$
such that $ax+ny=1$. Taking modulo $n$ of both side yields
$ax \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$.
Hence, by definition of inverse modulo $n$, $[a]$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $n$, say $[x]$. $\Box$.

${}$

**closure:** Let $[a],[b] \in U_n$.
Let $[a^{-1}]$ and $[b^{-1}]$ be the inverse of $[a]$ and $[b]$, respectively.
Now,
\begin{align*}
([b^{-1}][a^{-1}])([a][b]) &=
[b^{-1}]([a^{-1}][a])[b] \\
&= [b^{-1}]([a^{-1}a])[b] \\
&= [b^{-1}][1][b] \\
&= [b^{-1}b] \\
&= [1]
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
([a][b])([b^{-1}][a^{-1}]) &=
[a]([b][b^{-1}])[a^{-1}] \\
&= [a][bb^{-1}][a^{-1}] \\
&= [a][1][a^{-1}] \\
&= [aa^{-1}] \\
&= [1].
\end{align*}
Hence, $[b^{-1}][a^{-1}]$ is the multiplicative inverse of $[a][b]$.
Thus, $[a][b] = [ab] \in U_n$.

**well defined:**
Let $[a],[b],[c],[d] \in U_n$ where $[a]=[c]$ and $[b]=[d]$.
Then, $a \equiv c \pmod{n}$ and
$b \equiv d \pmod{n}$. Hence, there exists $p,q \in \Bbb Z$ such that
$a-c = np$ and $b-d = nq$. Now,
\begin{align*}
ab-cd &= ab-bc+bc-cd \\
&= b(a-c) + c(b-d) \\
&= bnp + cnq \\
&= n(bp+cq)
\end{align*}
Hence, $ab \equiv cd \pmod{n}$
i.e. $[ab] = [cd]$.

Thus, $\cdot_n$ is a binary operation.

Next, we want to show that $\cdot_n$ is assosiative. Let $[a],[b],[c] \in U_n$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
([a][b])[c] &= ([ab])[c] \\
&= [abc] \\
&= [a]([bc]) \\
&= [a]([b][c])
\end{align*}
Hence, $\cdot_n$ is assosiative.

Next, consider $[1] \in U_n$. Now,
$[1][a] = [a] = [a][1]$ for all $[a] \in U_n$.
Hence, $[1]$ is the identity element in $U_n$.

Finally, for all $[a] \in U_n$,
$[a]$ has a multiplicative inverse iff $\gcd(a,n)=1$, which is true by definition of the claim above.

Hence, $(U_n,\cdot_n)$ is a group.

Is the above true?

Comment: under **closure:**, you invoked inverses, which you haven't yet proved exist

Comment: You need to justify why these inverses exist, hint: what does Bezout's theorem tell you?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276644/prove-that-that-un-is-an-abelian-group) and compare it with your solution.

Comment: By Bezout's Lemma, there exists $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ such that $ax+ny = 1$. Now, $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. By definition of inverse of modulo $n$, then $[a]$ has an inverse modulo $n$, say $[x]$. Like this?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner How about now, Sir?

Comment: @NoahSolomon I have edit my attempt. How about now?

Comment: @DietrichBurde How about now?

Comment: @user795084 looks good to me

Comment: @NoahSolomon Okay, thanks sir!